# How to use if for this array

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to use if for this array :

```
    $options[] = array( "name" => __('slider Settings','wordpresstools'),
            "desc" => __('','wordpresstools'),
            "id" => $shortname."_favSlider",
            "std" => "",
            "type" => "select",
            "options" => array(
            'option1' => 'test',
            'option2' => 'test 2',
            'option3' => 'test 3'
));
```

if this select option = option1
echo " Test ";

I have more $options , but I want to if just for that option ( Slider Settings )

Thanks .

Comment: Please explain it more and share more code, what you wants to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem in your code are those brackets after `$options`. That way you append a new array element to the collection which means you have to test for something like this:

```
// Assuming your code creates the first array element
if ($options[0]['std'] == 'option1') {
    // Do your stuff
}
```

If you don't need the square brackets in your first line of code it would look like this:

```
$options = array(/* Your values */);

if ($options['std'] == 'option1') {
    // Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: This would have been worked in the code it was before. The author did edit his code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$shortname='test';
$options = array( "name" => create_function('slider Settings','wordpresstools'),
    "desc" => create_function('','wordpresstools'),
    "id" => $shortname."_favSlider",
    "std" => " I am here",
    "type" => "select",
    "options" => array(
        'option1' => 'test',
        'option2' => 'test 2',
        'option3' => 'test 3'
    ));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($options['std']);
```

If i am right you try to create a constructor function there. In order to do something like that you must use `create function`. [Read more details here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) The output of this code is printing `std` field as you want. The downside is that this method will be deprecated in PHP 7.2 so maybe you can find another work around than creating functions inside an array.

Answer (score 0):

Foreach loop on options

```
foreach($options['options'] as $k=>$v){
    // Check value of key
    if($k == 'option1'){
        echo $v . "\n";
    }
}
```

I'm not exactly sure what kind of implementation you need but this should be a decent start for however you're trying to use it.  I'm not sure if you mean to always have `option1`, `option2`, `option3`, etc. set or if you're checking to see if they exist.  If the prior, then you'd need to make a few slight changes; if the latter, then this should work fine as it will check every key value and it should only exist if the option is selected.